# What is the historical basis for the use of this type of phrasal verb in English but less so in Spanish?

Tags: syntax, cross-linguistic, verbs, history, phrasal-verbs

For example, English uses phrases like *to look for* and *to look at*, which (I believe) are considered phrasal verbs. Spanish, however, would under normal circumstances use some derivation of *buscar* and *mirar*, respectively, instead of a prepositional modifier.

Spanish does, however, use verbs that are partially comprised of a preposition, e.g. *soñar con* or *llevar a cabo*, as does Italian, e.g. *andare giù* and *andare via*. These are a type of phrasal verb, I believe, yet the primary root of the verb is different, unlike *to look for* and *to look at*.

Does this difference derive from the differing influences in the languages that influenced modern languages, e.g. Spanish has many Arabic influences, while English, perhaps fewer Arabic influences but more Germanic sources?

Comment: Nice question, and I think the upvotes prove that. :)

Comment: @Alenanno I need to ask more questions on here. I've learned quite a bit just from these answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a brief comment on the more Englishy aspect of the question.

The difference between Spanish and English in this regard is not connected to Arabic.  Rather it’s a **Germanic versus Romance** feature: Germanic languages as a whole have phrasal verbs (in which a particle, frequently homophonous with a preposition, is syntactically separable from the verb, as in *look it up*), Romance languages do not (such “preposition”+verb combinations as they have are not syntactically separable; this inseparability survives in Germanic borrowings, like *commit*, *remit*, *admit*, *permit*, resulting in roots, such as *mit* do not occur without a prefix).

Within English, you need to distinguish between *look for* and *look up* type verbs.  In the former case, *for* is the preposition used if there is an object; in the latter, *up* is always present, as a necessary part of the meaning.  Hence, the following is possible (no object, no *for*):

> A: Did you look for them?
>
> B: Yes, I looked all morning / Yes, I spent the whole morning looking

In contrast to:

> A: Did you look them up?
>
> B: ??Yes, I looked all morning / ??Yes, I spent the whole morning looking

There are also syntactic differences.  A object can intervene between verb and particle, or it can follow the particle:

> I looked them up
>
> I looked up the answers

This variation is unavailable for verbs that select a prepositional, rather than a nominal, complement:

> I looked for the answers
>
> *** I looked them for

Comment: +1 for stating that these particles are not always prepositions despite what many people incorrectly believe.

Answer (score 3):

Languages like Spanish and Italian exhibit *verb-framing* behaviour, meaning that the manner of the action (e.g. *scendere*, *cadere*) is encoded in the lexical item. On the other hand, English exhibits *satellite-framing* behaviour, since for many verbs, the same kind of information (motion from where? to where?) is encoded in particles which "orbit" the verb. It's true that neither is English entirely satellite-framing (through its Romance-derived verbal lexicon), nor Italian entirely verb-framing (with *giù* and *sù*).

As for the diachronic reasons, I think that all the Romance languages are largely verb-framing because Latin was strongly verb-framing (its rich set of preposition-like prefixes including *ob-*, *ab-*, *trans-*, *sub-* serving the same purpose as verb particles like *against*, *across*, *under*).

Daniel Harbour's answer has an important point, though. The verbs which he calls "*look up* type verbs" are instances of the English verb particle construction, which yields the verb/satellite-framing variation previously discussed. The "*look for* type verbs" are typically analysed as verbs which subcategorise for a PP (prepositional phrase), which explains why they cleave tight to the verb.

Comment: Incidentally, "look for" and "look at" can be converted to verb-framed versions "seek" and "view" (both without prepositions), respectively. However the result, though not ungrammatical, does sound quite strange to native speakers. (perhaps unrelated but "view" and "seek" both seem to be, at least partly, of PIE origin where as "look" seems to be Germanic)

Comment: @acattle: *seek* doesn't seem to have a clear PIE cognate.

Comment: [My source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=seek) says it's influenced by both Germanic and PIE words. I'm not particularly confident in that source, nor am I particularly familiar with historical linguistics but I thought it was an interesting coincidence that the verbs compatible with verb-framing may come from the same source as modern Romance Languages (which exhibit verb-framing). It needs a lot more research but I thought it was worth sharing.